# SSO Configuration on a Keycloak with existing user federation

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, federation

I am trying to set up SSO between two Keycloaks. The target Keycloak, where I want to configure the SSO has user federation set up in place and the user management is disabled. I was thinking of configuring IdP brokering between my source Keycloak and the target Keycloak so that I can use the same authentication token.

I have configured login redirection and when I try to login to the target system, I was promptly redirected to the source Keycloak. Unfortunately, upon entering the username and password, I was presented with a dialog box stating that my user already exists and offering me to either Review the profile or Add to existing profile.

Initially, I thought it is because the user modification is disabled by the user federation. I have manually created the same username on the system, which is providing a list of the users but even with this in place, I am still unable to log in and am presented with exactly the same error message.